# Close button in dismissable sidebar widget overlays over the top bar

Tags: bug

The sidebar widget on `hover` shows the close button (as expected)

[image: Side bar widget image]

But if we **scroll down**, the close button is kept over the top bar (not as the rest of the widget) as shown below

[image: Side bar widget image - button overlays]

[image]

In order to reproduce the issue we just have to hover one of the widget when its close button position match the position of the top bar (see below image)

[image]

If you are impatient while doing the scroll to the proper position and hovering the widget at the same time, just locate the widget element `<div class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-block mt8 mb4 clc-dismissable">` and force the `hover` state. Then scroll down in order to get the widget up to the top bar.

PS: I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I didn't use the exact correct term at some point here.

Comment: If you have to force it by manually setting state attributes, why is it a bug? There are all kinds of ways you can break functionality by fiddling with the HTML. I don’t see how you’d manage to hover over a widget that was outside of the viewing frame. Is the hover state *persistent* after you move the pointer away? If so, then you could reproduce it by simply hovering.

Comment: @CodyGray, No, you don't have to "force" it, just by hovering the widget div (as a regular user would do), if the widget is placed "under" the top bar, the issue happens. I just updated the post in order to make it clearer. I guess I did not explain well that part the first time.